# Vitest with vue3 composition setup complaining about function is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vitest

I am using Vue3 with composition api, typescript and setup. In my component I am importing 3 components of which one is dynamically chosen to load inside a  tag:

```
<component :is="getComponent(application.status)" >
```

The function `getComponent()' is declared in the script section and returns the right component to be rendered.

But when running a test Vitest is complaining about:

```
 $setup.getComponent is not a function
```

I am using Vue test utils to create a wrapper:

```
describe('PersonList with multiple persons', () => {


  const wrapper = mount(ApplicationDetailItem, {
    global: {
      plugins: [createTestingPinia(
        {
          initialState: initialState,
          createSpy: vi.fn,
        }
      )],
    },
    props: {
      isLast: false,
      applicationStatus: TestDataApplicationStatus1
    }
  })

....
....
```

How can Isolve this issue en why in first place is Vitest complaining?

Comment: The [documentation of getComponent](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/getcomponent.html) shows to use getComponent on the object returned by `mount`. So I'm guessing `<component :is="wrapper.getComponent(application.status)" >` in your case? Also shouldn't `application.status` be `applicationStatus` based on the props you posted..?

Comment: application.status is in my case a different value :). This is v1 documentation. I on v2. Solved it by refactoring my code

Comment: Oh okay sure. Hey you can post your own answer if you've solved it, that's valid